# Здравствуйте, как в с# от индекса а до индекса б ничего не делать с массивом а дальше заменить на ноли?

Tags: c#, массивы

Данные в массив поступают с консоли. Массив одномерный. В коде не знаю как написать именно что диапазон от а до b не трогать а дольше все поменять на ноль

---

Есть массив одномерный его размер и заполнение числами вводится с консоли. Дальше поступает число а это начало интервала и второе число b конец интервала. Вот от а и до b не трогать в массиве элементы а все остальные поменять на ноль. Гарантируется что a < b, a и b >= 0, a и b< размера массива

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я не понимаю что означает часть вопроса *от индекса а до индекса б ничего не делать с массивом*. Чтобы ничего не делать с массивом надо... ничего не делать с массивом ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `var result = array.Select((item, index) => index is >= 3 and <= 5 ? item : 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```cs
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // Массив собственно.

var a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Получаем с консоли значение, разбираем в число и присваиваем к а.
var b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Получаем с консоли значение, разбираем в число и присваиваем к b.

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { // Цикл который проходит по всему массиву
    if (i < a || i > b) { // Если индекс элемента ниже а или же выше б, то есть не в диапазоне [а, b]...
        array[i] = 0; // ...заменяем элемент на 0.
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо надо проверить ли у меня так получится

Comment: Аккуратней с `array.Length`, за пределы выходите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ изначально другой цикл писал. Потом цикл поменял, а условие забыл обновить. Исправил.

Comment: Да вышел за пределы, не полусилось
Я изначально написала что
For(i=a; b < numbers. Lingth; i++) И вроде работает но не знаю как дальше массив заменить на ноли

Comment: Простите неправильно написала
for( i=a; i< b+1; i++) вот так работает и выдаёт из массива именно то что надо но дальше не знаю как записать все на ноли

Comment: @Татьяна дальше `array[i] = 0;`